# Wordpress, trying to map a gravity forms checkbox field to an advanced custom fields checkbox

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, advanced-custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Wordpress site where I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin to add custom fields to the users. Then, I have a gravity form set up using the user registration add on. When the user fills out the gravity form, it updates their user information including the ACF fields. The problem I'm having is with the ACF checkbox field. When the user fills out the corresponding checkbox in the gravity form, it unchecks all of the boxes in the ACF user checkbox field. I tested it, and if only one checkbox is checked it works correctly, but when more than one is checked, it unchecks all of them. I read that Gravity forms stores the information from a checkbox differently than ACF and that's why they're not mapping correctly. Is there a code I could use to fix this?

This is the code I tried:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "acf_post_submission", 10, 2); function acf_post_submission ($entry, $form) { $post_id = $entry["post_id"]; $values = get_post_custom_values("valuestest", $post_id); update_field("field_57e3fd440d6b4", $values, $user_id); }
```

My gravity form id is '1'. The checkbox field ID in the gravity form is 4, and my ACF checkbox field name is valuestest (fieldkey field_57e3fd440d6b4)

Comment: Can show the code which you have done for Gravity Form action handler?

Comment: I used this which was provided by ACF support, but it isn't working. 'add_action("gform_after_submission_1", "acf_post_submission", 10, 2);

function acf_post_submission ($entry, $form)
{
   $post_id = $entry["post_id"];
   $values = get_post_custom_values("valuestest", $post_id);
   update_field("field_57e3fd440d6b4", $values, $user_id);
}'

My gravity form id is '1'. The checkbox field ID in the gravity form is 4, and my ACF checkbox field name is valuestest ( fieldkey field_57e3fd440d6b4).